# My sister has been offered a job in the US and they want to sponsor her, but would she get the job or not in the US?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, employment, usa, foreign-employment

I'm 36, from Bedfordshire, United Kingdom (Luton, actually). My sister's 34 and has worked across the country as a lap-dancer at various lap-dance bars, nightclubs etc. for the past 13 years now. She's not in it for the men or anything sex-related, she's always been very into dance as it is.

She told me last week that a club in New York phoned her having found her professional website and offered her a job, saying they'd sponsor her for the visa and handle everything. She told me how excited she was.

I'm not an expert on immigration but is the employer allowed to do this and sponsor her for a visa (she told me they'd sponsor her for a H1B, Google-ing tells me it's a specialist US visa).

Is it not allowed for the club to offer to sponsor her, they said they liked the fact she'd had 13 years of experience in lap-dancing (not counting a short 6-momnth stint as a car saleswoman) and really wanted to employ her and have invited her for interview in mid-September in New York (around Manhattan, IIRC).

My sister wants to take the job but is unsure of the practicalities about immigration to the US, employment etc.

Can anyone please explain what she'll need to do to actually get the job, and also, is the employer breaking any US laws I know of? I know over here we couldn't employ any US citizens for this sort of job because the job has to go to British or EU citizens first.

I've Googled the club she mentioned and it's genuine, gets good reviews, so this job isn't fake, but is it unusual for a lap-dancing club to head-hunt someone via their personal site?

We're currently on holiday up in Edinburgh, using the wi-fi so I may not have time to respond just yet.

Would really welcome the advice!

Comment: @DipenShah but the workplace question was closed as off topic.

Comment: @DipenShah I generally don't follow links that have been hidden behind the meaningless word "here."

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert but H-1B may not be applicable as its a specialty work, where the employer has to prove that they could not find the person with the specialty skill in USA and hence requesting H-1B for their "new" employee. The "New" employee offer would be contingent upon getting the H-1B visa. But, H-1B visa can not be obtained like any other visa.. there is a quota of (I guess) 65000 per year and the applicant could be about 150000, so its lottery. 
Second, This could be a scam so watch out for it. 
Third, For Artists or Athletes performing in US and earning, the Visa is most likely O1, P1 or P3. I would suggest search for it.

Comment: There's also an H-1B1 sub-category for 'fashion models'.

Comment: @brhans I just searched for H1B1 and found that it is for nationals of Singapore and Chile only. Source wiki.

Comment: My mistake - H-1B**3** is for "fashion models of distinguished merit and ability".